# Magento APIs mapping to Mobile Per Screen API Request

Tags: api, magento2.2, mobile, rest-api

I'm leading an API team on Magento 2.2 in supporting a mobile development team.

The mobile team is asking for APIs to be developed that support an **"API per Page"** type of architecture where they are saying this is a **standard pattern.**

**The Magento APIs do not support this type of architecture pattern; obviously as this unique to the app.**

I'm trying to determine if the mobile team is correct in their approach or if the Magento APIs were specifically built to support Mobile App architecture pattern.  Any thoughts?

**Are other mobile apps using Magento building out custom APIs and generally ignoring the OOTB APIs?**

Answer (score 1):

The answer we came too after doing some research is that the APIs are geared towards mobile browser not mobile app.

Apps we've seen that use the mobile APIs OOTB are designed to follow how the browser storefront works.

The goal of the mobile app development team is to minimize the number of calls the app makes and reduce the data being sent to just what the app needs. The app our team is designing doesn't follow the web site in UX thus some new APIs are needed to meet the requirements.

As a final note meeting the API requirements also highlighted that our Magento implementation will need to adjust how product attributes are managed.